# Very simple image loaded pretty slow with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a mobile application using the Flutter SDK and Dart, so far, I just got a simple User login form, the main widget over that is a ListView with the top widget as a Card widget with an image inside that works as a logo, my problem is, this logo takes like 1 to 2 seconds to load, and looks very ugly, I mean, when I launch the app, after the splash screen, all I see over my Card widget is a blank space, and after 1 to 2 seconds my image appears, it is very noticeable.

I read many ways to avoid this but none seem to work, the most common is to use precacheImage method to preload the image but that doesn't seem to work, I also tried this over the built as release and same thing happen, I must clarify that this logo is very small in size (100kB).

So far this is a part of my code, this HomeState class is just State of the Home stateful widget that is the body of a Scaffold widget that is the home of a MaterialApp, this is the main screen, so after the splash screen this is the first thing that loads,

```dart
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _minPad = 5.0;
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  ImageProvider logo;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    logo = AssetImage('images/logo_rienpa.png');
    await precacheImage(logo, context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
              child: Text('Rutinas de Mantenimiento',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
      body: loginForm(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }

  Form loginForm() {
    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minPad * 4),
          child: Center(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                getLogo(),
                Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 8, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: username,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      style: titleStyle,
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Por favor, ingresa tu nombre de usuario';
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Usuario',
                          labelStyle: titleStyle,
                          hintText: 'Ingresa tu usuario',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                    )),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 2, bottom: _minPad * 4),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: password,
                    obscureText: true,
                    style: titleStyle,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Por favor, ingresa una contraseña';
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Contraseña',
                        labelStyle: titleStyle,
                        hintText: 'Contraseña personal',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: _minPad * 2,
                      bottom: _minPad * 2,
                      right: _minPad * 20,
                      left: _minPad * 20),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Text(
                        "Ingresar",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            //code
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 10, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "No tienes un usuario?, registrate ",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(
                            'aqui',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return Register();
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                        Text(
                          ".",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      ],
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget getLogo() {
    Image logoImage = Image(image: logo, width: 250.0, height: 167.0,);
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: _minPad * 5, left: _minPad * 5),
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 8.0,
          child: logoImage,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
        ));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is my full code, they are three files.

main.dart:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rutinas_de_mantenimiento/screens/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainApp());

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(AssetImage('images/logo_rienpa.png'), context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Rutinas de Mantenimiento",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey, primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart (place where the image is loaded)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rutinas_de_mantenimiento/screens/register.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _minPad = 5.0;
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  ImageProvider logo = AssetImage('images/logo_rienpa.png');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
              child: Text('Rutinas de Mantenimiento',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
      body: loginForm(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }

  Form loginForm() {
    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minPad * 4),
          child: Center(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                getLogo(),
                Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 8, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: username,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      style: titleStyle,
                      validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Por favor, ingresa tu nombre de usuario';
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Usuario',
                          labelStyle: titleStyle,
                          hintText: 'Ingresa tu usuario',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                    )),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 2, bottom: _minPad * 4),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: password,
                    obscureText: true,
                    style: titleStyle,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Por favor, ingresa una contraseña';
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Contraseña',
                        labelStyle: titleStyle,
                        hintText: 'Contraseña personal',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: _minPad * 2,
                      bottom: _minPad * 2,
                      right: _minPad * 20,
                      left: _minPad * 20),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Text(
                        "Ingresar",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            //code
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 10, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "No tienes un usuario?, registrate ",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          child: Text(
                            'aqui',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                              return Register();
                            }));
                          },
                        ),
                        Text(
                          ".",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        )
                      ],
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget getLogo() {
    Image logoImage = Image(image: logo, width: 250.0, height: 167.0,);
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: _minPad * 5, left: _minPad * 5),
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 8.0,
          child: logoImage,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
        ));
  }
}
```

And resgister.dart I think this is not needed but here it goes

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return RegisterState();
  }
}

class RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController fullName = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController confirmPwd = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Rutinas de Mantenimiento',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: registerForm(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }

  Form registerForm() {
    var _minPad = 5.0;
    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minPad * 4),
        child: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Registro de usuario",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: null,
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 14, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: fullName,
                  style: titleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Por favor ingresa tu nombre completo';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Nombre completo", hintStyle: titleStyle),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 2, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: username,
                  style: titleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Por favor ingresa un usuario';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Nombre de usuario", hintStyle: titleStyle),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 2, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: email,
                  style: titleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Por favor ingresa tu Email';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration:
                  InputDecoration(hintText: "Email", hintStyle: titleStyle),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 2, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: password,
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: titleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Por favor ingresa una contraseña';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Contraseña", hintStyle: titleStyle),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _minPad * 2, bottom: _minPad * 2),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: confirmPwd,
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: titleStyle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Por favor repita su contraseña';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Confirme contraseña", hintStyle: titleStyle),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: _minPad * 4,
                    bottom: _minPad * 2,
                    right: _minPad * 20,
                    left: _minPad * 20),
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      "Registrar",
                      textScaleFactor: 1.5,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          //code
                        }
                      });
                    }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried building in profile mode?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm new to flutter, no idea what is profile mode, will try it

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/ui-performance

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I had the same problem with my drawer background image and I solved it with the precache Image, i guess you are using the precacheimage on the wrong place. you need to understand that in order to show the image correctly you need to load the image on app start and not till the state is initiated.
try this:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(AssetImage("images/logo_rienpa.png"), context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fethi',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
      ),
      home: new HomeState(),
    );
  }
}
```

On the HomeState page you don't need to use didChangeDependencies(), just declare the image on the definition like this :

```
 ImageProvider logo = AssetImage("images/logo_rienpa.png");
```

Comment: I thought it would work but it didn't, I saw no improvements at all, but thanks for your answer

Comment: there should be a mistake somewhere, send the full code or a link to your repo

Comment: I already update the question, let me know if you notice something wrong, and thank you in advance @Fethi

Comment: i don't know why actually, my code is the same as yours and it work fine for me,i suggest you try with another image, a jpg image

Comment: Well, I solved it, I discovered that my image was 5000x5000, and I resized it to 600x600, however this didn't solve anything, no improvements at all, but saving the image as jpg did it, thank you

Comment: This worked great when loading my asset images. Thank you.

Comment: I am using Getx package and I expirience very crazy behaviour after trying this solution. The Navitator became crazy and started to return the page to the cached image page.

Comment: As @Ronald Petit said, saving the image as jpg did it.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, for me i reduced the the image from 5000 x 5000 to 250 x 250 since they weren't bigger than that in the app files went from 11mb to 75kb, then in Photoshop i also exported it as a smaller file (8 bit) which took it to like 35kb. I would have tried jpeg but i needed the transparent background! but the mass reduction in file size helped me.

Comment: I discovered that the issue was not really the image extension or the size, it was the compile mode, I was testing it on Debug, where all the hot reload features and in screen messages really slow down the application, compiling in release mode speed up the application in like a 500%

Comment: Yeah i tried release mode with mine but it still loaded slow, which is fair since it was loading a fair few images at a larger side, although the application in general does speed up a lot in release mode!

Comment: @RonaldPetit You are right. I thought image loads were janky but it turned out that debug mode is always much slower and it's never the case in release mode. Thanks.