# Image in a Drawer not loaded immediately

Tags: image, flutter

I have an image saved in a dedicated directory in my flutter project. The entire directory is included as asset in pubspec.yaml, the code where it is shown is this:

```
        Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage('immagini/liberty_square.jpg')),
              SizedBox(height: 4),
              ListTile(
                // contents
              ),
             // etc...
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Drawer is located in a StatefulWidget. The image weighs about 2MB. It's a photo of a square in a town. I haven't used DrawerHeader to avoid paddings and margins.

In the android simulator (android studio), the image is loaded immediately as I open the Drawer, instead in my two real devices I have problems.

At app start I open the Drawer, but I can't see the image. Sometimes I have to wait some seconds to see the image, but other times I have to close and re-open the Drawer many times to see the image.

This happens both in test mode (android studio) and in production mode (apk installed and opened, without a pc).

I have thought to pre-load, but the image is an asset, not downloaded from network.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very simple image loaded pretty slow with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434003/very-simple-image-loaded-pretty-slow-with-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [precached image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) to load the image before the drawer is built.
Go to the widget that contains your drawer and add this to your `initState`:

```
precacheImage(new AssetImage('immagini/liberty_square.jpg'));
```

Then just call your image the same way you do now.